# how to build nextjs with fallback: true enable

Tags: next.js

I'm unable to find any examples of what needs to be done to deploy nextjs with fallback: true enabled.

using export it throws an error that it can't be exported this way if fallback: true is enabled.

And if I use `npm run build` it doesn't seem to generate the out folder.

How can I run a build and generate the out folder with fallback: true enabled in my app

netlify.toml
[build]
command = "npm run build && npm run export"
publish = "out"

package.json
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"export": "next export"
},

Answer (score 2):

You can't use use `npm run build` to generate static 'out' folder (i.e. static html-files). Thats becouse with fallback enabled, your site became 'non-static'. So it can be deployed only on servers thats run NodeJS. You may start server with `node start` or implement your own NodeJS server. This is a most misunderstanding point about SSG\SSR. More info at [https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-exporthttps://)

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation) you can't use `next export` if you use `fallBack: true`, if you have a lot of dynamic pages, better host your application on any node.js server and use `next start` instead.  Static HTML Export (out folder) is only useful when the new pages are not added often

Answer (score 1):

The other posts didn't explain why it doesn't work.

If you have `fallback` as `true` that means you have pages with dynamic routes  (`path/[pid].js`) and you DON'T want to pre-render all the pages. You want some pages to load without data, maybe because you want to load data manually.

When you use NextJS's `export`, it creates a static app with no supporting  backend so that the app can be served on a static host.

For each pre-rendered path, NextJS will generate a directory structure to match the prerendered path.

If you have:
`product/1`, `product/2`, `product/3` then NextJS will create those directories.

But if you have routes that are not prerendered like `product/4` then NextJS will not create that directory, then when the user opens their browser to `exmample.com/product/4` it will 404!