# Nextjs staticPaths fallback: true, does not generate new pages that are created after build

Tags: next.js

I have a situation where I am generating blog pages with `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`, now since we want to be creating new pages and have these pages available on the website without having to restart the server, I have tried to enable `fallback` in `getStaticPaths`

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = ...code to get paths...

  return {
    paths: paths,
    fallback: true
  };
}
```

Then in the `getStaticProps`

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  try {
    const post = await fetchPost(...someid...);

    return {
      props: {
        post
      },
      revalidate: 60
    };
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      notFound: true
    };
  }
}
```

So far so good!

If I run `yarn build` and then `yarn start`, create a new page with `/somenewslug` and then I try to open the page, it gets generated! Woohoo! So far so good.

However, there is one edge case that I dont know how to handle.

The edge case is if I try to open `/somenewslug` **BEFORE** the actual page is created, so when the page does not exist, `getStaticProps` will then return `notFound` (which is correct! for this point in time) and when I create the page after that, it will not work, it will keep giving me 404, and not try to refetch it but the page now exists.

I have also tried adding `revalidate` in conjunction with `notFound` (dont know if that can even work), but it didnt change anything.

Fallback I am handling with:

```
const SlugPage: NextPage<any> = props => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const router = useRouter();

  if (router.isFallback)
    return (
      <Loader
        colors={{
          backgroundColor: theme.colors.earth.second,
          color: theme.colors.earth.fifth
        }}
        loading={true}
      />
    );

    ...rest of normal page...
```

Comment: Did you create a fallback page?

Comment: I have a loader that I use when `router.isFallback` is true

Comment: Have you checked after 60 seconds?

Comment: @BrandonHan I have deployed it with revalidate and notFound together to test it on Vercel and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use `revalidate` with `notFound` together.

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  try {
    const post = await fetchPost(...someid...);

    return {
      props: {
        post
      },
      revalidate: 60
    };
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
      revalidate: 60
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70750585/22330398) explains well, you just have to host in a Node.js supporting server, and you don't have to give `next export` command.